# How to retrieve in a variable the result of a query to export it in pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

I'll explain a quiet better here. I've this method wich returns me some lines of ma table according to a searchstring I informed in my textbox.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string site, string searchString)
    {
        var user = from m in db.OrderDetails
                   select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            user = user.Where(s => s.Order.ClientID.Contains(searchString));                
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(site))
        {
            user = user.Where(c => c.Order.SiteNumber.Contains(site));
        }

            return View(user);            
    }
```

In the same class, I've an other method which generate a pdf file (all the backend process is set up in a second project include in the first).

```
  public ActionResult PrintOrders()
    {
        var user = from m in db.OrderDetails   
                   select m;                               

        return this.ViewPdf("Facture", "PrintView", user);
    }
```

This second method, when it generate my pdf file, displays all the entries of my table. I would like that, when I click on my link (on the same page view wich display my table entries) for generate my pdf file, if I did a search before, I juste have fields that match my searchstring (or site string).

How can I implement it ? There is a way do to it ? 
Thanks for your help, and sorry for the title which is maybe not too relevant. Also sorry for my english, hope you'll understand my aim.

**EDIT INFORMATIONS**

After looking, when I set up my PrintOrders() method like my Index() method as follow :

```
public ActionResult PrintOrders(string searchString, string username)        
{
            var user = from m in db.OrderDetails select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                user = user.Where(s => s.Order.ClientID.Contains(searchString));               
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(site))
            {
                user = user.Where(c => c.Order.SiteNumber.Contains(site));               
            }

            return this.ViewPdf("Facture Krys-Group", "PrintView", user);
        }
```

and set my view like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintOrders", "Historic", FormMethod.Get))
{ 

      Seach by ID : @Html.TextBox("searchString")

      Search by Site : @Html.TextBox("site")

      <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
}
```

then it works. **But I've already the same form in my view for "Index" instead of "PrintOrders". How can I combine both ?**

Comment: Does really db.OrderDetails contain users ?

Comment: Yes, I can retrieve in my view, all my fields, or just those which match my query. But in my PDF, for now I just can retrieve all my fields.

Comment: I think it will be possible to link "searchstring" and "site" (which are my Textbox) with my two forms, to have to informed it just once but I don't see how to do this. Or maybe an other solution will be better

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow you completely but I think you achieve what you are looking for with the use of partial views. The form you mention can be a partial view that gets rendered into the pdf view and like that you really have one form but displayed in both pages. Hopefully I understood what you were after and this helps you.

Comment: Hi, sorry my post is a little messy... You're right, now I can generate my pdf with the fields I ask, but to do it, I need to informed my "Searchtring" (or the other) in my form link to my PrintOrders() method. I would like end with one form, which allow me to do a search when I click submit1 (for example), and if the result is ok then I click submit2 to generate my pdf. The problem is my textbox I think, I am obliged to defined them twice in my case for now. Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the mess of my explanation